# Interesting Problem on Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A particular $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ has an eigenvalue of −1. The matrix $A+I$ reduces to

$\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 0 & -2 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}$

Corresponding to the eigenvalue −1, all the eigenvectors of A are non-zero vectors of the form:

(a)$\begin{bmatrix}
       2t\\
       0 \\
       t
     \end{bmatrix}$
(b)$\begin{bmatrix}
       2t\\
       s \\
       t
     \end{bmatrix}$
(c)$\begin{bmatrix}
       t\\
       0 \\
       -2t
     \end{bmatrix}$
(d)$\begin{bmatrix}
       t\\
       s \\
       2t
     \end{bmatrix}$

My approach:
As

$A+I=\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 0 & -2 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}$

$A=(A+I)-I = \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 & -2 \\
       0 & -1 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & -1
     \end{bmatrix}$

As $(A -\lambda I)X=0$

$\begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 & -2 \\
       0 & -(1+\lambda) & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & -(1+\lambda)
     \end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix}
       x\\
       y \\
       z
     \end{bmatrix} = 0$

By putting $\lambda=-1$ and solving linear system of equations we'll get $z=0$. Eigen vector should be of the form

$\begin{bmatrix}
       s\\
       t \\
       0
     \end{bmatrix}$
    $x=s, y=t, z=0$

But ans is given as

$\begin{bmatrix}
       2t\\
       s \\
       t
     \end{bmatrix}$

What and where I've made any wrong assumption

Comment: "...are non-zero vectors of the form..."? Is there a question here somehwere?

Comment: You have missed the $-\lambda$ in $A-\lambda I$ at its $(1,1)$ entry.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Thanx Silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector $\;v\neq 0\;$ is an eigenvector of $\;A\;$ corresponding to th eigenvalue $\;\lambda\;$ iff $\;(A-\lambda I)v=0\iff v\in\ker A+\lambda I\;$

Calculating then the zero space of $\;A+I=A-(-1)I\;$ , which is easily seen to be

$$\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\;\;:\;\;\;x=2z\;\right\}=\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}2t\\s\\t\end{pmatrix}\;\;:\;\;\;t\in\Bbb F\;\right\}$$

we get what we want.

Why you did $\;(A+I)-I\;$ and all that I can't understand.

Comment: To regain the original matrix $A$

Comment: @Atinesh What for? You don't need it. I think that perhaps the fact written in the first two lines above was forgotten by you.